# ajaxComplete with getJSON causing loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, getjson

I am using ajaxComplete to run some functions after dynamic content is loaded to the DOM. I have two separate functions inside ajaxComplete which uses getJSON.

- Running any of the functions once works fine
- Running any of them a second time causes a loop cause they are using getJSON.

How do I get around this?

I'm attaching a small part of the code. If the user has voted, clicking the comments button will cause the comments box to open and close immediately.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        // Lets user votes on a match
    $('.btn-vote').click(function() {
        ......

        $.getJSON(path + 'includes/ajax/update_votes.php', { id: gameID, vote: btnID }, function(data) {
            ......
        });
    });

        // Connects a match with a disqus thread
    $('.btn-comment').click(function() {
        var parent = $(this).parents('.main-table-drop'), comments = parent.next(".main-table-comment");

        if (comments.is(':hidden')) {
            comments.fadeIn();
        } else {
            comments.fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: To explein better the scenario post a piece of your code please.

Comment: @BorjaTur I edited the post above

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by checking the DOM loading ajax request URL

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(event,xhr,settings) {
var url = settings.url, checkAjax = 'list_matches';

if (url.indexOf(checkAjax) >= 0) { ... }

}
```